# Django ORM get latest item for each group

Tags: python, django, orm

I am using Django 2.2.1 with MariaDB 10.3.15.

I have this models:

```
class Hose(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)
    number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

class HoseHistory(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("date", "hose", "hose_event"),)

    date = models.DateTimeField()
    description = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)
    hose = models.ForeignKey(Hose, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hose_event = models.ForeignKey(HoseEvent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now I want to get a list of all entries of the Hose Table with, if there is one, the latest HoseHistory row.

The resultset should look like that:

```
| Hose.description | Hose.number | HoseHistory.date | HoseHistory.description |
===============================================================================
|    Example A     |      1      |    2019-01-09    |         Event A         |
|    Example B     |      2      |       NULL       |          NULL           |
```

So in detail Django should create a SQL Query which selects the Tabele Hose, LEFT JOINs the table HoseHistory, then group by Hose.number and then all MAX on HoseHistory.date.

I tried for example:

```
Hose.objects.values("number").annotate(max_date=Max("hosehistory__date")).order_by("hosehistory__date")
```

But the problem is that with this strategy I only have the column `max_date` and `number`, if I add more columns those will be added to the `GROUP BY` Statement and this query will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method in model

```
def latest_history(self):
    return HoseHistory.objects.filter(hose=self).order_by('-date').first()
```

and call in your template: `{{ hose.latest_history }}` if latest history exists

Comment: At the moment I have a solution which does exactly this, but for larger Datasets (in my case there are about 1000 hoses) this is extremely inefficient.